# how to create a model Object with dynamic keys in Java

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a scenario where I need to create a model object for the Json which looks like.

```
{
  "id":"12345",
  "What is the name of your first car": "a",
  "Mothers maiden name": "b",
  "Which city you are born in": "c",
}
```

Where the key 2,3,4 are dynamic(different for different requests), how to write a model object for this in java

Comment: Seems like you just want a hashmap.

Comment: so it would be three hashmaps one for each key

private String identity;
 private Map<String, String> question1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
 private Map<String, String> question2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
 private Map<String, String> question3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: A map can store multiple key/value pairs. You don't need one for each key, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Can you post an example, this model object I wanted to use as a requestBody for a POST request, which donot seem to work

Comment: Are you using any library to deserialize your JSON? Can you add some context to your post?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this :

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
class Model {
    private int id;
    private List<Question> listQuestionWithPropoedAnswers;
}

@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
class Question {
    private String question;
    private List<String> proposedAnswers;
}
```

Where each model have a key and a List of Question, where each Question have a question and proposed answers.

---

<sub>@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor, from the lombok project.</sub>